# Partitioned Sequence / Identity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given a table like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_bh_test](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Agency] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [Num] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (1, 1, 2015, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (2, 1, 2015, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (3, 1, 2016, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (4, 2, 2015, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (5, 2, 2015, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (6, 2, 2016, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (7, 2, 2016, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (8, 3, 2015, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (9, 3, 2015, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] ([Id], [Agency], [Year], [Num]) VALUES (10, 3, 2016, 2)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[_bh_test] OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Index [UIX_Agency_Year_Num]    Script Date: 4/17/2017 10:42:15 PM ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_Agency_Year_Num] ON [dbo].[_bh_test]
(
    [Agency] ASC,
    [Year] ASC,
    [Num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I want the `Num` column to always have a value that is unique across that particular `Agency` when inserting. Additionally, I want it to be a number that has never been used before.

So for example if I am inserting a value with agency 3, then a good candidate for `Num` would be 3.

It would seem I could use a default/binding to a function that would take the MAX(Num) + 1 with a group by for Agency. However, I wasnt able to send in the Agency to the function. But futhermore if the MAX(Num) was 2 and I inserted in 3...Then deleted 3, and inserted again it would reuse a Num of 3, which is wrong because I only want it to use a Num that has never been used before.

It sounds like an ideal solution for me would be a sequence that keeps track of a counter. Although it seems I cant used the PARTITION BY in the OVER in a SEQUENCE. Also the Num may be set manually so If the sequence was +1, and two values were inserted using the default seq. so now counter is at 2...it may be that 3 is manually inserted, and then next insert by default would be 3.  I would have to make sure to update the sequence on INSERT

I am not sure the best approach. I think using an INSERT TRIGGER is an option but I am not sure how to get around the whole problem if the MAX() is deleted and an INSERT is done.

Comment: Forget about fiddling with MAX to get the next number - it fails when more than one person tries to get it in parallel. I'm reading your requirements and thinking there is a design problem here. If it needs to be unique why not just use `[id]`? it's guaranteed to be unique. What is the purpose of the unique `[num]`? In your sample data agency=1, num=1 is used twice (line 1 and 3) so perhaps I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: num is unique only within a agency/year, it is an identifer only within that year. There are additional columns/metadata that I left out in order to simplify the problem but the idea is that `num` refers to a unique object and we are looking at a historical table where 1,2015,1 is the metadata for object `1` inside agency `1` in 2015 and 1,2016,1 is the metadata for object `1` inside agency `1` in 2016.

Comment: In a relational database this is achieved by creating a seperate master table (with a primary key). Then you create a foreign key to your master table.